# What part of jQuery UI puts the ui-widget-loading class on and how can it be removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to integrate jQuery UI tabs with knockout and I'm having a problem with tabs added at the start of my js. They seem to have a class `ui-tabs-loading` and I'm not sure why.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edhedges/mPbAL/

As you can see at the bottom of the js I am removing that class, but if you comment that out it breaks the first three tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "answer" your question, the `ui-tabs-loading` class appears to be added when an ajax request is spawned to fill the tab content (source: line #801 - https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js). As to *why* this particular case is being treated as ajax by jQuery UI, I'm still looking into that because I'm curious.

I know that jQuery plugins historically don't work well with javascript data-binding frameworks, but there's definitely always a work around.

I'll update my answer if I figure something out.

Comment: Not sure if you knew, but you can link straight to the line: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js#L801

I already saw that which is why I am confused as to why it would think it's an xhr. I'm going to continue to work on this as well, but since I did technically ask that in the question I will mark your answer as correct.

thanks